# check for several conditions when a user logs in

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to accomplish the following:

If a username or password field is null, notify the user.  If user name already exists, do not insert into the database and notify user to create a different name. if the username is unique and password is not null, return the username to the user.
As of now it always returns "Please enter a different user name." I believe the issue has to do with the database query but I am not sure. If anyone can have a look and see if I am making an error, I greatly appreciate it, thanks.

```
if ($userName or $userPassword = null)
{

  echo "Please enter a user name and password or return to the homepage.";

}

elseif (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT count(userName) FROM logininfo WHERE userName = '$userName'")) ==1)

{

  echo "Please enter a different user name.";

}

elseif ($userName and $userPassword != null)

{

  echo "Your login name is: $userName";

}
```

Comment: Just a note - how is `$userName` escaped? Because you are using it in two different contexts there - SQL and (assuming) HTML, both which require different escaping.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($userName or $userPassword = null)
```

This checks if the `$userName` is `true` (equivalent to `$userName == true`), and you're **assigning** `null` to `$userPassword`. You want something like `$userName == '' || $userPassword == ''`.

```
"SELECT count(userName) FROM logininfo WHERE userName = '$userName'"
```

Risk of [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) before plugging values into queries!

Also, `mysql_num_rows` will **always** return 1 row, hence this expression is always `true`. You need to look at **the value** of this one row.

```
elseif ($userName and $userPassword != null)
```

If this check was what you'd intend it to be, it'd be redundant with the first check.

Use something like this:

```
function validateUser($username, $password) {
    if ($username == '' || $password == '') {
        return 'Please enter a user name and password or return to the homepage.';
    }

    $query = sprintf("SELECT COUNT(*) as `count` FROM `logininfo` WHERE `userName` = '%s'",
                     mysql_real_escape_string($username));
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result) {
        trigger_error(mysql_error());
        return false;
    }
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    if ($result['count'] > 0) {
        return 'Please enter a different user name.';
    }

    return "Username: $username";
}

$result = validateUser($username, $password);
if (!$result) {
    // something went wrong, deal with it
} else {
    echo htmlentities($result);
}
```

Note that this is still far from ideal code, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: `$userName` may *already* be escaped for SQL. But then it wouldn't make sense to interpolate it as is in a string (see OP's example). Something is not quite right :)

Comment: @alex To be honest, I doubt it's escaped. :o)

Comment: this code works as far as checking to make sure both form fields are not null, and it also works to check the database; however, now it does not report user-names that are valid and have been added to the database. i'm sure it's something simple I am missing.

Comment: @paul That's because there's no adding to the database going on here. Good luck in getting things working, you'll have to write your apps yourself, this is only an example to get you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You might need the below. Very basic, though.

```
isset($_POST['username']) or die('username not given'); //#1
isset($_POST['password']) or die('password not given'); //#2

$escapedUsername = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST);
$result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT count(userName) FROM logininfo WHERE     userName = '$escapedUsername'"))

if ($result){
    echo "Hello, $escapedUsername"; //#3
}else{
    echo "Invalid Password"; //#4
}
```

But may I suggest something different. Will require you to change some portions of your app though.

- have this file as some login.php
- Use this for login/password reset/register/etc..
- have a GET to differentiate between these requests
- Use **AJAX**.
- In that case replace the following something like the below:

  - #1 : `die('{"RESULT":"ERROR", "DESC" : "USERNAME NOT GIVEN"}');`
  - #2 : `die('{"RESULT":"ERROR", "DESC" : "PASSWORD NOT GIVEN"}');`
  - #3 : `die('{"RESULT":"ERROR", "DESC" : "INVALID USERNAME/PWD"}');`
  - #4 : `die('{"RESULT":"SUCCESS", "DESC" : "$escapedUsername"}'); // can also use json_encode($result) here.`

These are just my suggestions. I have assumed mysql doesnt give you any problem. :-)

Comment: If he's sending these from a normal login form, isset will always return true.  An empty form field will still send you an empty string.

Comment: I have suggested AJAX. This is the reason why I did that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($userName or $userPassword = null)
```

should be

```
if (($userName == null) or ($userPassword == null))
```

However, I suspect you don't actually want to check if these are null.  Assuming you're filling these variables from input fields, an empty text field is NOT null; it's an empty string.  You can do `!empty($userName)` to check for an empty text field.

If you want to check two variable in single conditional, you have to write out each check separately - `($userName and $userPassword != null)` won't work the way you expect it to, it should be `($userName != NULL and $userPassword != null)`.

Also, when you're checking if a variable is equal to something, you have to use the `==` operator.  Otherwise, you're assigning the variable to that value, which is pretty much never what you want to do.